# Javascript multiple replace with regex that avoids html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a java script that finds vowels and capitalizes them. What I want to do is create a id called bigBlue that changes the capitalized values into blue characters with specific css properties.

```
var strMessage1 = Emphathy;
var startDiv = '<div id="bigBlue">';
var endDiv = '</div>';
var newRoot = strMessage1
.replace(/a/g, startDiv+'A'+endDiv)
.replace(/e/g, startDiv+'E'+endDiv)
.replace(/i/g, startDiv+'I'+endDiv)
.replace(/o/g, startDiv+'O'+endDiv)
.replace(/u/g, startDiv+'U'+endDiv)
$("#test").append(newRoot);
```

Here is the with the result [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv77q/)

My output is pretty much broken gibberish. What im thinking is that the .replace is also replacing the properties of the startDiv and endDiv.

How do I avoid the replacement of the startDiv and endDiv values, while replacing the vowels with the capital vowels, inclosed in the big blue div?

Comment: can you provide sample input and sample output? possibly [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Sure the JS Fiddle has been added http://jsfiddle.net/Vv77q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use function to replace instead direct symbols like that

```
var newRoot = strMessage1.replace(/[aeiou]/g, function(sym){return startDiv+sym.toUpperCase()+endDiv});
```

sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv77q/6/)

if you want that chars was on one line - use `<span>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: and remove the <style> tags around the CSS in the jsFiddle to make them actually blue ;)